# Search through text file and return a line of text

Tags: vb.net, do-while

I am trying to create a program that will search a text file for a line of text and then return the full line of information.

Example line: Joe Blogs JBL 1234

Search: Joe Blogs

Search returns: Joe Blogs JBL 1234

To make it as simple as possible, I have 2 text boxes & 1 button.

Textbox1 = search

Textbox2 = Search results

Button = Search button

Can anyone tell me how to do this because I'm finding it really difficult. I'm new to VB coding so the simplest of code would be helpful!

This is what I have so far:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Input Text Error 

    If TextBox1.TextLength = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a Staff Name or Staff Code", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
    End If

    'Perform Search

    Dim strText As String = SearchFile("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\Extentionlist.txt", TextBox1.Text)
    If strText <> String.Empty Then
        TextBox2.Text = strText
    End If

End Sub

'Search Function

Public Shared Function SearchFile(ByVal strFilePath As String, ByVal strSearchTerm As String) As String
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strFilePath)
    Dim strLine As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
            strLine = String.Empty
            strLine = sr.ReadLine
            If strLine.Contains(strSearchTerm) Then
                sr.Close()
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        Return strLine
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function

'Clear Button

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub

' Open The text file 

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Process.Start("C:\Users\kylesnelling\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\Extentionlist.txt")
End Sub

End Class
```

Whenever I perform a search, all I get back is the last line of the text file... does anyone know why?

Comment: `If strLine.Contains(strSearchTerm)` ? . Additonally you should enclose your `StreamReader` in a `Using` block to e´nsure proper disposing.

Comment: Plus: `Dim strText As String = SearchFile("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\Extentionlist.txt", Textbox1.Text)` without double quotes.

Comment: how do enclose a stream reader into a block? i have made the changes you suggested however every time i search something it only brings up the final line of the document and doesn't actually perform a search as such

Comment: Can you edit your question with your current code please? And see this example how to use [Using](https://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader-vbnet)

Comment: All done for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex B has stated in comments, line `If strLine.Contains("textbox1.text")` should be `If strLine.Contains(strSearchTerm)`

Also you are not passing in the search item to the function. The below line you have passed in the string textbox1.text as a string rather than the text inside the textbox. Hence why you never find the line you are searching for and always returns the last record of your file.

`Dim strText As String = SearchFile("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\Extentionlist.txt", "textbox1,text")`

This line should be:

`Dim strText As String = SearchFile("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\Extentionlist.txt", textbox1.text)`

Also with this line `Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\Extentionlist.txt")` why have you used the same path destination when you have already passed in this file location in the variable `strFilePath`.

line should be `Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strFilePath)`

Its best to use the variables being passed into the function otherwise this function won't be very useful to other parts of code that may be referencing it or if search terms or filepaths change.

Updated from comments: 
`strLine.ToUpper.Contains(strSearchTerm.ToUpper)`  this line will make both text uppercase and the word you are searching for to uppercase,  which will allow them to ignore case sensitivity, so for example, "text" can match with "Text" by both being converted to "TEXT" when used to compare.

Comment: re-updated with the code for alex B, implemeted both changed that you have recomended thanks for the help so far :D

Comment: Cal-cium i'm not really sure what i'm actually doing i have done a few things in VB before but i'm trying to learn it at the moment i don't fully understand everything as of yet

does anyone know how can actually make it search the file and return the data i would like?

Comment: What is it doing now that you have changed it?

Comment: whatever search criteria i enter the result will always be the last line of the .txt document. if i add a new line to the .txt document and save it the search will always present the last line no matter what.

Comment: I would assume, either it could be a few things, i would try stepping through code to test this. 1. Is your loop actually looping through correctly? 2. is the search term actually in the text? and in same text format eg same case?

Comment: Try
            Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
                strLine = String.Empty
                strLine = sr.ReadLine
                If strLine.Contains(strSearchTerm) Then
                    sr.Close()
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop

Comment: Try this: `strLine.ToUpper.Contains(strSearchTerm.ToUpper)`

Comment: apologies that was supposed to be the loop i think its correct im not sure 

i have edited the question up top and that is exactly the code i have right now infront of me, i have searched the exact word and it still does not work

Comment: you my friend are an absolute genius!

Comment: it did! it actually searched and returned my results! your a legend!

Comment: No problem :) Please accept this answer as accepted for other people who maybe looking for similar help to know it's solved. :)

Comment: Also by the way, you might want to put in some sort of check to see if the text you are looking for is not found, for example if user enters wrong information, it won't find it and will return last line of file again. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try friend.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim searchResult As String = SearchFile("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\Extentionlist.txt", _
                                            "text to search for")

    Me.TextBox2.Text = searchResult

End Sub

Public Shared Function SearchFile(ByVal strFilePath As String, ByVal strSearchTerm As String) As String


    Dim fs As New System.IO.StreamReader(strFilePath)

    Dim currentLine As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Dim searchResult As String = String.Empty


        Do While fs.EndOfStream = False
            currentLine = fs.ReadLine
            If currentLine.IndexOf(strSearchTerm) > -1 Then
                searchResult = currentLine
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop


        Return searchResult

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function
```